# How can I get Results faster for my MINLP Optimization with APM GEKKO?

Tags: performance, optimization, gekko, mixed-integer-programming

I am trying to do an Optimization for the Energy Supply of an domestic House. The energy demand should be satisfied by a Heat Pump, PV-Modules, Electric Water Heater and the public electricity Grid. Also the Energy System consists of an Battery Storage an a Heat Storage. The only (binary) integer Variable in my Program is the Heat Pump. My Goal is to Optimize the System over the Timeframe of 1 Year (8760 timesteps). When I run the Code with 1800 timesteps I get results in about 500 seconds. For 4500 timestamps it already takes about 9 Hours. For the full 8760 timesteps the code is still running (since about 24 Hours) without any solution. In earlier iterations of the code it ran for more than a Week without generating results. I already tried a few things I read here to speed up the optimization. Is there anyway I can get the Program to find a solution faster? Since I am a beginner at Python it is very much possible that my Code is inefficient. I would very much appreciate it, if someone has an Idea that can get me faster Results or estimate the time the program takes to find a solution. Thank you very much in advance.

Here is my Code, I have shortened the Arrays for the Energy-Demand to 100 Values to shorten my Code:

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt



timesteps= 100
m = GEKKO(remote=False)
t = np.linspace(0, timesteps-1, timesteps) #Zeit
m.time = t

m.options.SOLVER = 1 
m.options.IMODE = 6 
m.options.NODES = 2 
m.options.REDUCE=3
m.solver_options = ['minlp_maximum_iterations 1000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 1000',\
                    'minlp_integer_tol 1.0e-1',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',\
                    'objective_convergence_tolerance 1.0e-4',\
                    'minlp_gap_tol 9e-1']
    
# Energy Demand

    #1. electricity
    
EL_Demand_Arr1=np.array([1.9200000,1.4890000,1.4920000,1.1300000,0.64099997,0.58600003,0.58399999,0.61000001,0.54900002,0.59500003,0.92699999,0.95599997,0.91000003,1.1450000,1.1090000,1.6360000,1.4740000,1.4680001,2.6150000,2.1810000,1.2320000,1.3700000,0.96899998,1.3220000,1.1880000,0.64399999,0.53899997,0.55299997,0.52899998,0.56099999,0.54600000,0.80000001,1.1350000,0.70700002,1.1680000,1.0440000,2.3160000,1.6420000,2.2370000,2.8870001,1.8550000,1.4030000,0.70599997,1.4980000,3.4879999,1.5130000,1.4349999,1.3520000,1.0530000,0.51700002,0.55000001,0.52800000,0.52999997,0.56199998,0.53700000,0.58999997,0.53500003,0.92500001,1.3490000,0.66299999,4.3810000,1.0200000,0.79799998,0.77899998,1.0840000,2.1530001,3.7449999,5.3490000,1.8710001,2.3610001,0.78799999,0.47099999,0.56800002,0.51700002,0.54799998,0.55699998,0.51400000,0.56500000,3.2790000,2.2750001,1.2300000,0.97899997,0.78200001,1.0140001,0.77800000,0.58099997,0.52999997,0.55900002,1.1770000,1.5400000,1.4349999,2.0400000,2.2790000,1.6520000,1.6450000,1.2830000,0.55800003,0.52499998,0.51899999,0.53799999])
EL_Demand_Arr2=EL_Demand_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
EL_Demand_Arr=EL_Demand_Arr2[0:timesteps]

EL_Demand=m.Param(EL_Demand_Arr,name='EL_Demand')
    
    #2. heat
    
H_Demand_Arr1=np.array([1.0960000,1.0790000,1.1590000,1.1760000,1.6940000,2.2639999,2.1450000,2.0769999,2.0720000,2.0300000,1.9069999,1.8810000,1.7880000,1.8180000,1.8049999,2.0430000,2.1489999,2.1700001,2.1830001,2.1910000,1.9920000,1.5290000,1.1810000,1.0400000,1.4310000,1.4110000,1.4700000,1.4900000,1.8880000,2.4530001,2.2809999,2.3199999,2.2960000,2.3299999,2.1630001,2.1289999,2.0599999,2.1090000,2.0940001,2.3450000,2.4380000,2.4679999,2.4630001,2.4480000,2.2219999,1.8480000,1.5779999,1.4310000,1.5000000,1.4790000,1.5410000,1.5620000,1.9790000,2.5720000,2.3910000,2.4319999,2.4070001,2.4430001,2.2679999,2.2309999,2.1589999,2.2110000,2.1949999,2.4579999,2.5560000,2.5869999,2.5820000,2.5660000,2.3290000,1.9380000,1.6540000,1.5000000,1.7160000,1.6930000,1.7630000,1.7869999,2.2650001,2.9430001,2.7360001,2.7839999,2.7539999,2.7950001,2.5950000,2.5539999,2.4710000,2.5300000,2.5120001,2.8130000,2.9250000,2.9600000,2.9549999,2.9370000,2.6659999,2.2170000,1.8930000,1.7160000,1.7980000,1.7670000,1.8789999,1.9160000])
H_Demand_Arr2=H_Demand_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
H_Demand_Arr=H_Demand_Arr2[0:timesteps]

H_Demand=m.Param(H_Demand_Arr,name='H_Demand')
    
    #3. Domestic Hot Water
    
DHW_Demand_Arr1=np.array([1.7420000,0,0,2.0320001,0,0,3.7739999,2.4960001,3.3670001,0,2.4380000,1.1030000,0,0,0,3.1350000,2.2060001,0,4.4120002,0,0,0,0.87099999,1.5089999,0,0,0,0,0,0.87099999,0.81300002,1.1610000,2.5539999,1.6260000,0,0,0.63900000,0,3.4830000,2.8450000,2.4960001,7.1409998,5.7480001,2.3800001,3.1930001,0,1.1610000,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2.6129999,1.9160000,4.2379999,0.34799999,5.4569998,0,0,2.8450000,0,0,0,0,0,2.4960001,1.6260000,0,2.5539999,0,0,0,0,0,1.6260000,0,3.0190001,0,2.8450000,1.1030000,2.9030001,0,0,0,0.98699999,0,1.1610000,0.34799999,1.3930000,1.2770000,4.4120002,0,0,0,0,1.8580000,0,0.98699999])
DHW_Demand_Arr2=DHW_Demand_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
DHW_Demand_Arr=DHW_Demand_Arr2[0:timesteps]

DHW_Demand=m.Param(DHW_Demand_Arr,name='TWW_BED')
    
    #4. electricity production from PV
    
PV_P_Arr1=np.array([0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.057000000,0.14399999,0.30500001,0.13600001,0.28900000,0.22000000,0.0040000002,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.061999999,0.78899997,0.56300002,0.13600001,0.052999999,0.017000001,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.037000000,0.098999999,0.15000001,0.11200000,0,0.12600000,0.032000002,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0.0040000002,0.73600000,1.8250000,2.4020000,3.1870000,0.66500002,0.045000002,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])
PV_P_Arr2=PV_P_Arr1.round(decimals=3)
PV_P_Arr=PV_P_Arr2[0:timesteps]

PV_P=m.Param(PV_P_Arr,name='PV_P')
    
# Heat Pump "Bit" ist '1' during the Heating Season and '0' outside the heating Season to tell the Promgram that the Heat Pump may only be used during heating Season

HP_Bit_Arr1=np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1])
HP_Bit_Arr=HP_Bit_Arr1[0:timesteps]

HP_Bit=m.Param(HP_Bit_Arr,name='HP_Bit')   



# Battery Storage

B_S = m.SV(0,lb=0) 
B_S.FSTATUS=1
m.fix_initial(B_S,0)

B_S_Load = m.SV(0,lb=0) #Loading Battery
B_S_Recover = m.SV(0,lb=0) #Recover Energy from Batterie

eff_B_S = 0.95 #efficiency Battery


# Heat Storage

H_S = m.SV(0,lb=0) 
H_S.FSTATUS=1
m.fix_initial(H_S,0)

H_S_Load = m.SV(lb=0)    #Loading Heat Storage
H_S_Recover = m.SV(lb=0) #Recover Energy from Heat Storage

eff_H_S = 0.9 #efficiency Heat Storage

#Heat Pump

# Binary Variable for Heat Pump (it can either be turned on '1' or off '0')
P_HP_Binary=HP_Bit*m.sos1([0,1])
P_HP_Binary.STATUS = 1 

#Electrical sizing of the Heat Pump

P_el_HP1= m.SV(0,lb=0)
P_el_HP1.FSTATUS=1

#Electrical Water Heater

EH=m.SV(0,lb=0)
EH.FSTATUS=1


# The Power of the Heat Pump multiplied with the Binary Variable gives the actual Output of the Heat Pump

P_el_HP=m.Intermediate(P_HP_Binary*P_el_HP1)

COP_HP=3.5 #COP of the Heat Pump

Q_HP=m.Intermediate(COP_HP*P_el_HP) # thermal Energy Output of the Heat Pump

# the objective of this Optimization ist to minimize the Cost for the Energy-System, scince you only Pay for the maximal Value of the Heat Pump, Energy Storages and the electrical Water Heater and not for the value at each timestep, I define a FV that describes the maximal Value of the Components

P_el_HP_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Heat Pump
P_el_HP_max.STATUS=1

H_S_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Heat Storage
H_S_max.STATUS=1

B_S_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Battery
B_S_max.STATUS=1

EH_max=m.FV(lb=0) #Electrical Water Heater
EH_max.STATUS=1

# We have energy Production from PV, there ist a possibility to give Energy thats not needed to the public Grid

I_Excess=m.Var(0,lb=0)

# In Case we have more Demand for Electrical Enery than Production from PV we have the possibility to get Energy from the public Grid

I_feed_out=m.SV(0,lb=0)
I_feed_out.FSTATUS=1

# Volume of the Heat Storage in m^3

Vol_HS=m.Intermediate((H_S_max*3600)/(1000*4.18*(35-10)))



# boundary conditions 

m.Equations([PV_P +I_feed_out + B_S_Recover - P_el_HP - B_S_Load - I_Excess - EH == EL_Demand, #Energy Balance needs to satisfy the Demand
             
             B_S.dt() == B_S_Load - B_S_Recover/eff_B_S, #Loading and Recovery of the Battery
            
             B_S_Load * B_S_Recover == 0, #It is not allowed to Load and Recover at the same Time, at least one of both needs to be equal to '0' at each Timestep
             
             P_el_HP*COP_HP + H_S_Recover - H_S_Load + EH == H_Demand + DHW_Demand, #The Demand of Heat and DHW needs to be satisfied at each timestep
             
             H_S.dt() == H_S_Load - H_S_Recover/eff_H_S, #Loading and recovery of the Heat Storage
             
             H_S_Load * H_S_Recover == 0, #It is not allowed to Load and Recover at the same Time, at least one of both needs to be equal to '0' at each Timestep
             
             
             # The maximal Value of the Enery System Components is the Upper Bound for the Value at each time Step
             
             P_el_HP1 <= P_el_HP_max,
             P_el_HP1 >= 0.4*P_el_HP_max, # the Heat Pump is a variable speed heat Pump and has a minimal output of 40% of the nominal Power
             H_S <= H_S_max,
             B_S <= B_S_max,
             EH <= EH_max,])

#Objective is to minimize the cost of the Energy System (the Cost of Components that only need to be bought once get divided by the number of timesteps)
           
Objective=(((P_el_HP_max*1918.4)*P_el_HP_max+(EH_max*50)+B_S_max*1664.9*B_S_max+(Vol_HS*2499.3*Vol_HS))/(20*timesteps)-0.05*I_Excess+0.35*(I_feed_out))

m.Minimize(Objective)

m.solve(disp=True)


#Print Results

print("Nominal Power of the Heat Pump=",max(P_el_HP),"kW")
print("maximum Capacity of the Heat Storage=",max(H_S),"kW")
print("Volume of the Heat Storage=", max(Vol_HS),"m^3")
print("maximum Capacity of the Battery", max(B_S),"kW")
print("Electricity from the Public Grid",sum(I_feed_out[0:timesteps-1]))


# Plot results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(6, 1, figsize=(5, 5.1), sharex=True)
axes = axes.ravel()

ax = axes[0]
ax.plot(t, EL_Demand, 'r-', label='Electrical Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t, PV_P,'b:', label='PV Production',lw=1) #z.B. Generator (haben wir aber in unserem Energiesystem nicht)


ax = axes[1]
ax.plot(t, EL_Demand, 'r-', label='Electrical Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,I_feed_out, 'k--', label='Electricity from the public Grid',lw=1)

ax = axes[2]
ax.plot(t,B_S.value, 'k-', label='Battery Storage',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,B_S_Load,'g--',label='Battery Storage Loading',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,B_S_Recover,'b:',label='Battery Storage Recovery',lw=1) #lw=2 --> linewidth

ax = axes[3]
ax.plot(t,H_Demand, 'r-', label='Heat Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t, Q_HP.value,'b:',\
        label='Thermal Production Heat Pump',lw=1)

ax = axes[4]
ax.plot(t,H_S, 'k-', label='Heat Storage',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,H_S_Load,'g--',label='Heat Storage Loading',lw=1)
ax.plot(t,H_S_Recover.value,'b:',\
        label='Heat Storage Recovered Energy',lw=1)


ax = axes[5]
ax.plot(t,DHW_Demand, 'r-', label='Domestic Hot Water Demand',lw=1)
ax.plot(t, EH,'b:',\
        label='Electrical Water Heater',lw=1)




for ax in axes:
    ax.legend(loc='center left',\
              bbox_to_anchor=(1,0.5),frameon=False)
    ax.grid()
    ax.set_xlim(0,len(t)-1)

plt.savefig('Results.png', dpi=600,\
            bbox_inches = 'tight')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

The scale-up issue is likely with the heat pump binary variable. An exhaustive search for your cases leads to the evaluation of 2^8760 possible solutions. The APOPT solver uses a branch and bound method that greatly reduces the number of potential solution candidates. Here are [solver options](https://apmonitor.com/wiki/index.php/Main/OptionApmSolver) that are recommended to improve the speed and control the solution tolerance.

```py
m = GEKKO()
m.solver_options = ['minlp_gap_tol 0.1',\
                    'minlp_maximum_iterations 1000',\
                    'minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol 500',\
                    'minlp_branch_method 1',\
                    'nlp_maximum_iterations 100']
m.options.solver = 1
```

- **minlp_maximum_iterations** - maximum number of NLP solutions from the branch and bound method. A successful solution is returned if there is an integer solution upon reaching the maximum number of iterations. Otherwise, the solution is not considered to be successful and an error message is returned with the failed solution.
- **minlp_max_iter_with_int_sol** - maximum number of NLP solutions when a candidate integer solution is found
- **minlp_gap_tol**: gap is the spread between the lowest candidate leaf (obj_r=non-integer solution) and the best integer solution (obj_i). When the gap is below the minlp_gap_tol, the best integer solution is returned
- **minlp_branch_method**: 1=depth first (find integer solution faster), 2=breadth first, 3=lowest objective leaf, 4=highest objective leaf
- **nlp_maximum_iterations**: maximum number of iterations for each NLP sub-problem. Reducing the NLP maximum iterations can improve the solution speed because less computational time is spent on candidate solutions that may not converge

I recommend fine-tuning these solver options on a short time horizon problem, perhaps 100 time steps to solve in a few seconds. The improvement in computational speed should also apply for the larger problems.

Comment: Hello Mr. Hedengren,
thank you very much for your Answer, your answer Worked and it now solves faster.

Comment: Since I linearised the Cost function oh the Components I have a new problem that I would like to solve. The Cost-Function for the Heat Pump for example now has the Form: a+b*P_el_HP, which means that "a" are fix Costs that occur even if the Optimal solution would be one with P_el_HP=0 kW. I have tried to tell the Program that it only needs to pay the "fix Costs" if P_el_WP>0 by adding an m.if2/m.if3 statement of the form: m.if2/3(-P_el_HP_max,1,0) and multiplying that with the fix Costs "a", also I have tried to work with the m.sign2/3(P_el_HP) function.

Comment: Sadly none of these attempts worked and the Program always gives me a Solution, where P_el_HP_max=0 even thou that is not the right solution, I know that this is not the optimal solution, because I get a lower objective for the same timesteps, when P_el_HP_max>0. Maybe you can help me with that problem too, thank you very much! Best wishes.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please create a new question with your current code and an explanation of what is not working. Maybe try adding a constraint that `P_el_HP_max>=1e-3` to avoid a local minimum at `P_el_HP_max=0`.

Answer (score 2):

There are excellent suggestions in the other answer posted on tweaking GEKKO, which I'm not too familiar with, but the **main issue** you have is that you've made a non-linear model, which will be extraordinarily difficult to solve over that many time periods.  I'd strongly suggest:

1. Reformulate.  You can very likely make this linear.  You are multiplying variables together in several places, which makes the model non-linear.  There are linear formulations that could be substituted.  Find them all and fix them, even if you have to add more variables.  You might be able to make this a simple LP (no integer requirements) and it would solve in a snap.  For instance, you do not need to multiply the binary `heat pump` variable by the heat pump output to regulate that.  That is non-linear.  You should just be doing something like:

```
heat_pump_output[t] <= heat_pump_max_output * heat_pump_on[t]
```

where `heat_pump_max_output` is a fixed parameter (optionally time-indexed) and `heat_pump_on[t]` is either a parameter limiting on times or a binary variable, if needed.

There are several other parts that might be changed also, such as charge-discharge where you have 2 variables and might consider just one "flow" variable that can be positive or negative.  (This might be tough if you have different "efficiencies" for charging/discharging.)

There are also ways to linearize "or" conditions if that (above) doesn't work or if there are other needs with binary variables without multiplication.

2. Review your objective for non-linearities also.  It is unclear why you are squaring variables in your objective function when you are looking at costs
3. If the above is unsuccessful and you cannot linearize the model, then think about not solving for all time steps at once or just pick a much larger time step, perhaps aggregated to 6 observations a day at "stressful" times.

Here is a **highly similar** [model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71494297/python-pulp-linear-optimisation-for-off-grid-pv-and-battery-system/71501812#71501812) written in `pulp` that solves in about 30 seconds for 8000+ time steps.  Translation into GEKKO shouldn't be too daunting if you like that framework.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your quick answer! You are right, some Non-Linear Functions can be linearised to get Solutions faster. I have done that and it now solves faster. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Since I linearised the Cost function oh the Components I have a new problem that I would like to solve. The Cost-Function for the Heat Pump for example now has the Form: **a+b*P_el_HP**, which means that "**a**" are fix Costs that occur even if the Optimal solution would be one with **P_el_HP=0 kW**. I have tried to tell the Program that it only needs to pay the "fix Costs" if P_el_WP>0 by adding an m.if2/m.if3 statement of the form: m.if2/3(-P_el_HP_max,1,0) and multiplying that with the fix Costs "a", also I have tried to work with the m.sign2/3(P_el_HP) function.

Comment: Sadly none of these attempts worked and the Program always gives me a Solution, where P_el_HP_max=0 even thou that is not the right solution, I know that this is not the optimal solution, because I get a lower objective for the same timesteps, when P_el_HP_max>0. Maybe you can help me with that problem too, thank you very much! Best wishes.